# Django ORM: count a subset of related items

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am looking to find a way to annotate a queryset with the counts of a subset of related items.  Below is a subset of my models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    PracticeAttended = models.ManyToManyField('Practice',
                                              through = 'PracticeRecord')

class Club(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    Slug = models.SlugField()
    Members = models.ManyToManyField('Person')

class PracticeRecord(PersonRecord):
    Person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    Practice = models.ForeignKey(Practice)

class Practice(models.Model):
    Club = models.ForeignKey(Club, default = None, null = True)
    Date = models.DateField()
```

I'm looking to make a queryset which annotates the number of club specific practices attended by a person.  I can already find the total number of practices by that person with a query of `Person.objects.all().annotate(Count('PracticeRecord'))`

However I would like someway to annotate the number of practices that a person attends for a specific club.

I would prefer something using the django ORM without having to resort to writing raw SQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I would like someway to annotate the number of practices that a person attends for a specific club.

Let us see.

First, find the specific club.

```
club = Club.objects.get(**conditions)
```

Next, filter all Persons who have practiced at this club.

```
persons = Person.objects.filter(practicerecord__Practice__Club = club)
```

Now, annotate with the count.

```
q = persons.annotate(count = Count('practicerecord'))
```

**Edit**

I was able to successfully make this work in my test setup: Django 1.2.3, Python 2.6.4, Postgresql 8.4, Ubuntu Karmic.

**PS**: It is a Good Idea™ to use lower case names for the fields. This makes it far easier to use the double underscore (`__`) syntax to chain fields. For e.g. in your case Django automatically creates `practicerecord` for each `Person`. When you try to access other fields of `PracticeRecord` through this field you have to remember to use title case.

If you had used lower case names, you could have written:

```
persons = Person.objects.filter(practicerecord__practice__club = club)
#                                               ^^        ^^
```

which looks far more uniform.

**PPS**: It is `Count('practicerecord')` (note the lower case).

Comment: WOW, that is cool and works perfectly ... I didn't know that if I filtered on a particular field then the aggregation would also be on the filtered rows.  Out of curiosity do you know if this behavior is mentioned in the docs anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that raw sql is the only option here. Anyway it's not that scary and hard to manage if you put it to model manager.

Comment: Strange. I was able to get it to work without resorting to Raw SQL. Tested in Django 1.2.3, Postgresql 8.4, Python 2.6.4, Ubuntu Karmic.

Comment: Yes, there is way to annotate after filtering original queryset.I thought that task was to annotate practice records without filtering persons.